# Bind gridview to subset of array

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have an array of objects I get from a web service. The 1st element in that array is meant to be displayed in a asp.net literal control. The rest of the elements are meant to be bound to a gridview. So my question how do I bind n-1 elements of that array to the gridview?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Just found this new .NET array method.

```
Dim x() as MyObject = Provider.GetObjectArray()
x = x.Skip(1).ToArray
mygridview.DataSource = x
mygridview.DataBind
```